# How to loop URLSearchParams?

Tags: javascript, urlsearchparams

I tried those two options, without any luck:

```js
let url = new URL(window.location.href);
let key = undefined;

for (let k of url.searchParams) {
    if(url.searchParams[k] == postID) {
        key = k;
    }
}
```

and

```js
let url = new URL(window.location.href);
const filteredItems = Object.keys(url.searchParams).filter(key =>
  url.searchParams[key] == postID
);
let key = filteredItems.keys.first;
```

What is wrong?

Comment: In your first piece of code, `k` is an array like `[key, value]` (just console.log stuff)

Comment: Can you share a sample input and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: `const params = Array.from(url.searchParams.entries());` creates a two-dimensional array.

Comment: `for (let [key,value] of url.searchParams) console.log(key,value)`

Comment: `const key = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(new URL(window.location.href).searchParams).reverse().map(([a,b]) => [b, a]))[postId]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two issues:

1. While [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) have iterator semantics (i.e. a `Symbol.iterator` property), accessing the keys is not performed via normal property access, but via the `get` method: `url.searchParams.get("someKey") === postID`.
2. The iterator protocol of `URLSearchParams` returns elements as `[ key, value ]` arrays, not just the keys themselves, so in your `for`–`of` loop, `url.searchParams[k] == postID` is like `url.searchParams[[ "someKey", "somePostId" ]] == postID`, which will be coerced to `url.searchParams["someKey,somePostId"] == postID`.

A working approach for finding a key (or the *keys*) for which the value matches `postID` would look like this:

```js
const searchParams = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams;
// const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search); // Alternative.

const keyCandidates = Array.from(searchParams)
    .filter(([ key, value ]) => value === postID)
    .map(([ key ]) => key);
const keyCandidate = Array.from(searchParams)
    .find(([ key, value ]) => value === postID)[0];
const lastKeyCandidate = Array.from(searchParams)
    .reverse()
    .find(([ key, value ]) => value === postID)[0];

console.log("List of candidate keys: ", keyCandidates);
console.log("Single candidate key: ", keyCandidate);
```

If you’re in an environment where [Iterator Helpers](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) are supported, this can be rewritten as:

```js
const keyCandidates = searchParams.entries()
    .filter(([ key, value ]) => value === postID)
    .map(([ key ]) => key)
    .toArray();
const keyCandidate = searchParams.entries()
    .find(([ key, value ]) => value === postID)[0];
```

The `lastKeyCandidate` may have an easy equivalent in the future with the [Double-Ended Iterator proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-deiter).

```js
const lastKeyCandidate = searchParams.entries()
    .filter(([ key, value ]) => value === "1")
    .map(([ key ]) => key)
    .next("back") // Get last entry in iterator.
    .value;
```

---

More iteration examples:

```js
const url = "https://example.com/?some=value&search=1&param=&etc";

// Equivalent to `new URL(url).search`.
const urlSearch = "?some=value&search=1&param=&etc";

// Equivalent to `new URLSearchParams(urlSearch)`.
const searchParams = new URL(url).searchParams;

// Equivalent to `Array.from(searchParams.entries())`
console.log(Array.from(searchParams));
// Result: [ [ "some", "value" ], [ "search", "1" ], [ "param", "" ], [ "etc", "" ] ]

// Equivalent to `new Map(searchParams.entries())`
console.log(new Map(searchParams));
// Result: Map { "some" → "value", "search" → "1", "param" → "", "etc" → "" }

console.log(Array.from(searchParams.keys()));
// Result: [ "some", "search", "param", "etc" ]

console.log(Array.from(searchParams.values()));
// Result: [ "value", "1", "", "" ]

for(const [ key, value ] of searchParams){
  console.log(key, value); // "some", "value"; then "search", "1"; then "param", ""; then "etc", "".
}
```